# Dropdown inside nav, ul, li tag closing when trying to select despite e.preventDefault()

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, preventdefault

```
const DropdownButtons = () => {

      const SettingsDropdownMenu = () => {
        const settingsNavRef = useRef();
        const [isSettingsActive, setIsSettingsActive] = useState(false);

        useOnOutsideClick(settingsNavRef, () => {
          if (isSettingsActive) setIsSettingsActive(false);
        });
      
      const toggleSettingsNav = () => {
            setIsSettingsActive(!isSettingsActive);
        };
 
      return (
          <>
            <div 
            ref={settingsNavRef} 
            className="menu-container" 
            id="settingsButton">
              <button
                className={isSettingsActive ? "active" : "menu-trigger"}
                onClick={toggleSettingsNav}
              >
                <SettingsTwoToneIcon /> 
              </button>
              {isSettingsActive && (
                <div
                  onClick={() => setIsSettingsActive(false)}
                >
                    <nav className={`menu ${isSettingsActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'}`}>
                    <header class="menu-title">User: </header>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://m2.protectedseas.net/resources/M2_Cloud_Help.pdf" target='_blank'>Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                                        <form onSubmit={changeRadarHandleSubmit}>
                      <label>
                        Change radar:
                        <select name="selectedRadar">
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                      </label>
                </form>
                    </nav>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </>
        );
      };

    return (
        <>
        <CssBaseline />
      <Control position="topright">
              <ButtonGroup orientation="vertical" variant="contained">
                <Tooltip placement="left">
                    <SettingsDropdownMenu />
                </Tooltip>
              </ButtonGroup>
              <ButtonGroup orientation="vertical" variant="contained">
                <Tooltip placement="left">
                    <InfoDropdownMenu />
                </Tooltip>
              </ButtonGroup> 
        </Control>
        </>

    );
  };
```

When trying to select an option from the dropdown, the dropdown closes automatically when anything is clicked (eg. the dropdown icon). Initially, the dropdown form was inside the last li tag. I tried putting it outside but inside ul and I also tried putting it outside ul.

I have made sure to include e.preventDefault() in my handleSubmit function and it still closes automatically no matter where I place the form.

I also have a custom hook to close the nav when clicking outside of it.

```
export const useOnOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
        callback();
        console.log("click");
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
      };
    });
  };
```